# How do I predict the output of Python's random number generator?

Tags: python, random

Here is my code

```
from random import randint

print(randint(0,9))
```

Now I want to know which number it will generate if run this code. What is the algorithm behind it?

Is there a way I can change it.

If that does not work, then let me ask something different

```
from random import randint
for i in range(10):
    print(randint(0,9))
```

Let's take this example. This will print 10 random numbers

`list[2,1,4,5,2,4,5,2,1,5]`

If I know 9 numbers in the above list, is there a way to know the 10th number for that instance?

Comment: You can fix `random.seed` so the random numbers will be always the same

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator to understand the basic principles of "random numbers" in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a random number generator is to provide random numbers.
Ideally, no, there is no way to predict what's the 10th number given 9 numbers in the sequence (because, again,*that's not random*!)

What you can do is set the seed of the random number generator with `random.seed(some_value)`. By using the same seed, the sequence of numbers generated by subsequent calls to randint() will be identical (note: identical, **not** predictable).

Comment: Cool Lethr Thanks for the answer. I want to know if their is any rules for random like they will repeat the number from the previous number or not, or how many time a number will be repeated.Or any rules of random numbers in python will be helpfull.

Comment: By definition, a random number must be unpredictable. Anything short of that is not random. [Pseudo-random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (like that used by the `random` module) try to approximate this as much as possible, while guaranteeing that given a certain initialization (the seed) the sequence of numbers generated is deterministic. With that said, there is no way you can, **or should**, predict the next number in the sequence given the observed values (that would be a huge bug in the library!)

Comment: This is totally wrong. Approximately all PRNGs in use are perfectly predictable when observed enough values (LCGs, MersenneTwister, ... all default-prngs in various languages). This is not something they are designed for / or designed against. Only Cryptographic-PRNGs (e.g. [Blum Blum Shub
](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub)) are designed for exactly this purpose. The predictability has not much negative impact on the general usage though (except for example where this is a problem -> crypto; online-gambling)!